# Solutions to $|f(t_i)+g(t_i)|+|f(t_i)-g(t_i)|=1,i=1,2,3,4$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Does there always exists a solution in variables $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_1<t_2<t_3<t_4,t_i\in[0,1],i=1,2,3,4$ to the following system of four equations:
\begin{equation}
|f(t_i)+g(t_i)|+|f(t_i)-g(t_i)|=1
\end{equation}
where $f(t),g(t):[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are injective continuous maps with $f(0)=f(1),g(0)=g(1)$.

I know for many nice choices of $f$ and $g$ solution exists. Actually, I am trying to construct a counterexample, that is, functions $f,g$ with above properties with no solution.

Edit 1: Injective except at the end points.
Edit 2: Grave mistake. Changed plus sign to minus.

Comment: Are they supposed to be both indexed by $i$? Feels like you made a goof there.

Comment: Yes, indexed by $i$ both the functions.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $f(0)=f(1)$ then by the MVT there exists $0 <a<b<1$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: @snulty it is minus there. Edited

Answer (score 1):

How can $f,g$ be injective satisfying $f(0)=f(1), g(0)=g(1)$?

Comment: Sorry ...except at the end points.

Comment: Do they have to be continuous? I wonder if they can.

Comment: OOps...yes continous!! Edited

Comment: @ersh There's no function $f:[0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that would be continuous, satisfy $f(0) = f(1)$, and be injective expect for the end points. It's a direct conclusion from mean value theorem.

Comment: @Jakobian, yes thanks. But I will re post the question as my question is not clear in the current format.

Comment: This cannot be the case as if $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and injective on $(0,1)$ satisfying $f(0)=f(1)$ choose $p \in (0,1)$ sufficiently close to $0$ and $q \in (0,1)$ sufficiently close to $1$. Then with the map being continuous $f(p)$ is close to $f(0)$ and $f(q)$ is close to $f(1) = f(0)$. With the intermediate theorem we get numbers $a \in (0, p)$ and $b \in (q,1)$ satisfying $f(a) = f(b)$.